# Namespace not found class? symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Newbie problem here, I've created a Bundle named MyServices with Sub folder MyBundle,

I've created a Service named myAWServ but as I'm calling `$this->get('myAWS')->methodCall()` I'm getting the following error :

> CRITICAL - Fatal Error: Class 'MyServices\MyBundle\myAWS\myAWS' not
>   found  CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted
>   to load class "myAWS" from namespace "MyServices\MyBundle\myAWS". Did
>   you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" at
>   /home/sergio/Desktop/hello_symfony_heroku/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
>   line 1755

I've reviewed all files a hundred times and can't find the problem the files are as it follow:

```
<?php
//File Location : MyServices/MyBundle/Controller/myAWS.php
namespace MyServices\MyBundle\myAWS;

class myAWS
{
    public function __construct($greeting)
    {
        $this->greeting = $greeting;
    }

    public function greet($name)
    {
        return $this->greeting . ' ' . $name;
    }
}
```

The Root file created with the bundle (php app/console generate:bundle)

```
//Filesource : MyServices/MyBundle/MyServicesMyBundle.php
<?php

namespace MyServices\MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MyServicesMyBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

and the services.yml

```
parameters:
    myAWS.class: MyServices\MyBundle\myAWS\myAWS

services:
    myAWSer:
        class: "%myAWS.class%"
        arguments: [teste]
```

I've got it loading in the AppKernel 
            new MyServices\MyBundle\MyServicesMyBundle(),

Currently im doing  a simple call

```
<?php

namespace MyServices\MyBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        die($this->get('myAWSer')->greet($name));

    }
}
```

I've also tried  clearing the cache.
Sorry for the long post, and thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a `Controller` fraction in the path, but there is no such in the namespace. There is also `myAWS\myAWS` --- it's 2 `myAWS` while in the path it's only one `myAWS` entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
// File Location : MyServices/MyBundle/Controller/myAWS.php
namespace MyServices\MyBundle\myAWS;
```

Your file's path is `MyServices/MyBundle/Controller/myAWS.php` but you must follow your namespace, so the correct path should be `MyServices/MyBundle/myAWS/myAWS.php`. You should also check out the [psr-4 specifications for autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).